# Safari color with background transparency on disabled input

Tags: html, css, safari

When i use the css color #b3b3b3 on a disabled input it turns white?? why this is happening and how can i workaround?

Look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/esty6t20/

CSS:

```
.transp {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.bug-color {
  color: #b3b3b3;
}
.red-color {
  color: red;
}
```

HTML:

Disabled Bugged Gray

```
<input class="transp bug-color" value="test text" disabled>
<br/>
Disabled Red color
<input class="transp red-color" value="test text" disabled>
<br/>
Enabled Bugged Gray
<input class="transp bug-color" value="test text">
```

I already tried to force override the !important but with no success.
Check the result:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because of a weird bug. Input placeholder text has always been a bit of an issue because nothing seems to be a standard yet in which all browsers have successfully implemented just yet. So it's a pain to have it consistent across all browsers **easily**.

However, add the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property to your CSS and it'll work. It seems to be fine in Chrome so adding this will get it working nicely in Safari as well.

*Your CSS would be...*

```css
.bug-color {
  color: #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

*[**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color) about this property and [**CanIUse**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke) support table.*

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with `#b3b3b3` per se. If you set `color: #a8a8a8`, you will find that the text actually renders as `#fdfdfd`, which implies that Safari has an incorrect calculation on its color blending somewhere. Since `#b3b3b3` is even lighter, the blend error causes it to display as pure white.

Safari evaluates the `transparent` color as `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. If you instead set `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0)`, everything will display correctly cross-browser, with no need for `-webkit` properties.

If you also need to support IE11, make sure to include a fallback, i.e.:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

Comment: Turns out this is an old, known bug in WebKit that has never been accepted: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115510

Answer (score 0):

You should use the disabled selector, something like this:

```
input.bug-color:disabled {color:#0000ff;}
```

Comment: the problem is associated specific with the color #b3b3b3, using this approach the problem still happening.