# same css text color shows different color in safari compared to other

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to implement a simple `color` attribute in `CSS` and it works fine in mobile Google Chrome (Galaxy S10), but not in Mobile Safari (iPhone X):

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select {
    color: #777;
}
```

Utilizing this color displays a nice dark grey on all browsers but Safari. Safari turns this into an unreadable white color. I've checked the `CSS` and it's pulling the same color, so I'm not sure why the colors are displaying different. I've tried using a fully qualified color `#777777` and `color: black` to see if it makes a difference, but no luck. Below is a screenshot of what it looks like on Safari (iPhone X) and Chrome (Galaxy S10).

[image: Chrome]
[image: Safari]

Comment: What version is your safari?

Comment: Working fine for me in Safari 12.1.2

Comment: i have whatever is the lastest safari in iphone X

Comment: Working fine for me on iOS Safari 12.4 as well

Comment: Have you tried adding the `!important` attribute to it or making it an in-line style (these come first always by default)? Safari could be potentially overwriting it.

Comment: Can you supply a functional code snippet for us to look at? For example, just get the issue to recreate on a site like [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and supply the snippet here once you've created a minimal example that reproduces the issue. This will significantly increase your chances of getting an acceptable answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome renders colours differently from Safari and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing, and while a lot of the similar questions are dealing with disabled input text color, for me it's just happening in my button's normal state.

I recommend reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43483479/4530520 for more info and taking their suggestion of setting the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property.